# Can't get TestBookOrder to compile due to a char(java)

Tags: java

Sorry about this, but for some reason my program won't compile. I have a BookOrder class created with the following in it...

```
public BookOrder(String author, String title, int quanitity, double costPerBook, String orderDate, double weight, char type)
{
}
```

... but for reason, whenever I run my main method, with variables entered like this...

```
BookOrder BookOrder1 = new BookOrder("Jonathan", "Book1", 12, 6.75, "11/5/2013", 8.75,r);
```

I keep getting a compile error "error: cannot find symbol... symbol: variable r location: class TestBookOrder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the `char` within single quotes.

```
new BookOrder("Jonathan", "Book1", 12, 6.75, "11/5/2013", 8.75, 'r');
```

Comment: Thanks. Such a simple answer, can't believe I forgot that :\

Comment: Np. It happens a lot of times! :)

Answer (score 1):

All `char` are to be in single-quotes.

```
new BookOrder("Jonathan", "Book1", 12, 6.75, "11/5/2013", 8.75, 'r');
```

when you just write `r`, it looks for a variable with that name. If you do not have a variable with that name that corresponds to the appropriate type, it will be flagged as an error.

However, if you still want to keep `r` without the quotes, you can add this line somewhere before making the call:

```
char r = 'r';
```

Now, it wont be flagged as an error.